# Play/Stop Button in row at listView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

i need some help in this problem ,i have listview with row containing play/stop image and textView ,if i press the play image play sound and change the icon to stop image and inverse and if i press the row itself do the same things but the problem is when i press the row the image change it's ok but if press the image itself of next row change the image in selected row but not inverse the image of the row selected befor ,i want to reverse at each click on listview image wherever i press(row or image)

```
enter code here     azkar = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.add_playlist_listView);
        adapter = new SoundsAdapter(this, playlists,azkar);
        adapter.setCustomButtonListner(SoundsActivity.this);
        azkar.setAdapter(adapter);
        int lastPosition =-1;
        azkar.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            int pos;
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                adapter.getView(position, view, parent);
                try {
                    if (lastPosition != -1) {
                        View lastRow = azkar.getChildAt(lastPosition);
                        ImageView play = (ImageView) lastRow.findViewById(R.id.is_added);
                        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_background);

                        View currentRow = azkar.getChildAt(position);
                        ImageView stop = (ImageView) currentRow.findViewById(R.id.is_added);
                        stop.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop_background);
                    }
                    lastPosition = position;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                final HashMap<String, String> committee = playlists.get(position);
                String fileName = committee.get(CategoriesActivity.KEY_PATH);
                run(committee.get(CategoriesActivity.KEY_PATH), view, position);
            }
        });

enter code here   
 @Override
public void onButtonClickListner(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "aaaaaaa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final int pos = position;
    adapter.getView(position, view, parent);
    try {
        if (last != -1) {
            View currentRow = azkar.getChildAt(position);
            ImageView stop = (ImageView) currentRow.findViewById(R.id.is_added);
            stop.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop_background);

            View lastRow = azkar.getChildAt(last);
            ImageView play = (ImageView) lastRow.findViewById(R.id.is_added);
            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_background);

        } else {
            View currentRow = azkar.getChildAt(position);
            ImageView stop = (ImageView) currentRow.findViewById(R.id.is_added);
            stop.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop_background);

        }
        last = position;
    }catch (Exception e){}
    final HashMap<String, String> committee = playlists.get(position);
    String fileName = committee.get(CategoriesActivity.KEY_PATH);
    run(fileName, view, position);
```

}

```
enter code here            //code in adapter
    thumb_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                if (customListner != null) {
                customListner.onButtonClickListner(position, convertView, parent);
        }
        }
    });
    return vi;
}
public interface customButtonListener {
    public void onButtonClickListner(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent);
}

public void setCustomButtonListner(customButtonListener listener) {
    this.customListner = listener;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using for this behaviour  ?

Comment: before press the each row notify the adapter that data set changed like this:notifyDataSetChanged():

Comment: Can you please  show your code

Comment: this:notifyDataSetChanged(): not working ,the problem it's difficult to explain but i tried  to do best ,the problem appear when i press the row itself in listview  and change the image but  when press the image itself  in row not the row itself for another row of listview having different position of the previous selected

Comment: why don't you using two button. set visibility gone of  one button when another is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

**changes expected** Try this and try to customize according to your requirement. I have 5 items in listview. and the `listView.setOnItemClickListener` is working well.Its changing the only position you clicks and rest views will be auto update.
I can't do further.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
            View v;
            int count =5; //parent.getChildCount();
            v = parent.getChildAt(position);
            parent.requestChildFocus(v, view);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlayPause);
            imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
            int i=0;
            while ( i < count) {
                if (i != position) {
                    v = parent.getChildAt(i);
                    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlayPause);
                    imageView1.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);

                }
                i++;
            }

        }
    });
```